# Shortcut to open another workspace in sublime text

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

Sublime text lets you switch current project workspace with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> on Windows/Linux. I find myself often referencing older projects where I want to open another project quickly without closing the current one (which the above shortcut doesn't do).

[image]

Is it possible to pop open a dialog like the above project switcher one with a keyboard shortcut and open a new workspace without closing the existing one ?

Comment: Just use `ctrl+alt+p` after opening a new window via `ctrl+shift+n` should solve the problem.

Comment: Try my [open-sesame](https://github.com/gerardroche/sublime-open-sesame) Package Control plugin.